# Transparent Frame in CustomTkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, transparent, customtkinter

I am coding an application with customTkinter. For layout-reasons I used a frame (*player_frame*) that contains other frames (*p_frames*). I don't want the *player_frame* to be visible, so I tried to set it's color to "transparent" (note that *self* refers to a child class of customtkinter.CTk):

```
self.player_frame= customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")
self.player_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor= customtkinter.S)
```

Afterwards, the other *p_frames* are being added to the *player_frame* with a green background color.
[the grey part is the still visible player_frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dtA3.png)

How can I make the player_frame transparent? I read the documentation of CTk and it says that you can use *fg_color="transparent":

> argument: fg_color; value:    foreground color, tuple: (light_color, dark_color) or single color or "transparent"
> [customTKinter documentation](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/frame)

PS: My code is quite long, I hope that I submitted enough of it. If not, please let me know. I had the feeling that the problem is not because of my code but more because of something I didn't undestand in the documentation.

Thanks for your help!

I already tried to change the color of player_frame with:

```
self.player_frame= customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="red")
self.player_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor= customtkinter.S)
```

This works. So I guess there is something wrong with "transparent"

Comment: "transparent", in CTk, simply means that the widget automatically takes on the background color of its parent widget.  Actual transparency between widgets is simply impossible, the underlying Tk toolkit does not support it.